# Footer as a one of the item on the ListView.

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to achieve the effect of the footer for ListView but without using the `addFooterView` method of the ListView. My intention is to treat the last visible item of the list as a pinned footer. In my view I can achieve this by detecting the last visible item on the list and dynamically change it's layout. I did some research and I think I must extend the `BaseAdapter` class providing two types of items. One for ordinary item on the list indicating that adapter should inflate the item with ordinary layout. And the second one indicating that adapter should inflate the current item with layout of footer. I think i must override the `onScroll` method to detect the last visible item. And here are my questions. Should i call the `getView` method from the `onScroll`method ? Is it the proper way to implement such effect? Is it possible at all? I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Better to add another view below listview using data of the last element.

Comment: So you know about setFooterView but don't want to use it. Can you explain why? It's likely there's another problem with your code if you feel you're being forced to do it this way

Comment: I'm not forced to do do this in this way. I haven't started to implement it yet. My intension is to add new items to the list via the footer that is part of the list. And when the list is being scrolled and the footer reaches bottom edge of the view it is pinned to it. I'm just looking around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And here are my questions.
>   Should i call the getView method from the onScrollmethod ?

no, you should never directly call getView(). Only classes that extend `AbsListView` call `getView`

> Is it the proper way to implement such effect?

No. The proper way of doing it is calling `addFooterView` to your `ListView` object.

> Is it possible at all? I would be grateful for any suggestions.

No, it's not possible. Using scroll listeners you will never be able to find out when the `AbsListView` is requesting the "last view". That's because ListView does not guarantee the order it queries for Views. That's specially true when you 1st set the adapter or call `notifyDataSetChanged` which causes the ListView to get the views in several points to be able to layout and measure stuff it needs.

The suggestion is to use the `addFooterView` method, that's the correct way of doing, that's why it's there.